# Nikon 18-55 mm Lens Focus Wheel Jammed

Tags: lens, focus, equipment-damage

I accidentally dropped my Nikon D3200 with a 18-55 mm lens about a foot onto a hard carpet.  It originally looked ok, however I soon realised it wasn't focusing.  I saw that the focus wheel was jammed because the front end of the lens had been pushed in to the other part.
Here's a photo of the lens at the moment:
[image]

Comment: Trade it in for another lens. It won't have value as a trade-in, of course, but a good store will at least take it off your hands and give you a decent price on a used replacement.

Comment: Yikes, it's likely not worth having it repaired, but may be worth trying to pull the pushed in part back out.  Good luck.

Comment: I don't get why it looks so damaged. I only dropped it about 20cm onto a hard floor because I thought I had the strap round my neck. It doesn't seem a great build quality - I have done this on many occasions before with other lenses by accident with no damage before. You can still take photos, but the wheel is jammed even in manual focus so it will only take a picture in manual focus or if the subject is a certain distance away so that the focus is correct for the subject.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately unless you can fix the problem yourself, the repair will likely end up around as (or even more) expensive as a second hand lens of the same type. The 18-55 mm kit lenses are abundant since they come with the kits that people getting into DSLR photography are buying. When they upgrade their lenses they sell these lenses at low prices.